# Origin point not moving with armature

Tags: animation

I'm fairly new to blender, modeling and animation so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

I just made this model and the animation. But when playing the animation the origin point of all the different objects and the armature doesn't move.

[image]

[image]

I don't know if this is meant to happen or if I'm doing something wrong.

I plan to import the model and animation to Unreal Engine 4 and use the animation as root motion.

But as far as i understand, in order to use root motion at least the armature's origin point need to move with it?

I was wondering if there is a way to fix this or if I'm completely in the wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All good,  this is meant to happen.  The armature object location does not move when shifting pose bones, just as the mesh object with armature modifier does not move,  it moves (modifies) the vertices.  Not that  familiar with unreal engine, so guestimating that root motion could refer to the root bone  of the armature.  _It is often the case with game rigs that they are required to have a single root (top of hierarchy parent) bone_

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to make sure things were behaving as they should. I added a root bone to the armature and parented the rest of the bones to it, and now it works as intended.